# Append div blocks and change line automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't think of a good way to structure this piece of html/css.

say I have an area that is centered + middle 80% height + width, that means it resizes with the browser.

Now, I have a list of div tags being dynamically appended to this area by javascript. When a div tag hits the end of a line, it changes to the next line.

like this:

```
___________________________
| [AB] [CD] [EF] [GH] [IJ] |
| [KL] [MN] [OP] [QR] [ST] |
| [UV] [WX] [YZ]           |
|__________________________|
```

I have 100's of this div blocks, when browser changes size they may move and change lines altogether. Please suggest an efficient way to achieve this layout using html/css. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this javascript library http://isotope.metafizzy.co/, it might help you what you are looking to achive

Comment: @Vinod, very very nice plugin :D

Comment: I don't get these negative people who contributed to nothing but voted to close the post. The question is simple and clear, the answer from Vinod and Dfsq is awesome and both nail it with two distinct approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make divs float inside your container, which could be positioned absolutely/fixed with specified dimensions:

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="block">Block' + (this.children.length + 1) + '</div>');
});
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    background: #EEE;
    overflow: auto;
}
.container .block {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background: coral;
    float: left;
}
.container .block:nth-child(odd) {background: darkseagreen;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Block 1</div>
    <div class="block">Block 2</div>
    <div class="block">Block 3</div>
    <div class="block">Block 4</div>
    <div class="block">Block 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are awesome. very clean solution and totally solved my problem.